# how to make spacing between table rows

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate this table:

[image: table]

but the spacing between the rows (*border-spacing: 0 2px*) is not working, anyone knows why?

My code:

```html
<center>
<table style="z-index: 34; background-color: #57e8e8; width: 50%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 2px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 2px;">Usu&aacute;rio:&nbsp;<strong>teste</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: transparent; color: #131e2e; padding: 5px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0 2px;">Senha:&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>teste</strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, but `<center>` was deprecated in HTML 4.01. Might be a good idea to let that one go.

Comment: Due border-collapse: collapse ,  table borders are getting collapsed and together and border-spacing property has no effect with border-collapse: collapse use border-collapse: separate

Comment: Note that even with `border-collapse: separate`, the background color of your table will show through; make the background color of your `td` the blue color and the background color of your table transparent.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What about outlook? How can I center things for outlook users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the table cells a background-color, not the whole table. Then remove the border-collapse rules:

```css
table{
  z-index: 34; 
  width: 50%; 
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
}

td{
  background-color: #57e8e8;      
  color: #131e2e; 
  padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<center>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="">Usu&aacute;rio:&nbsp;<strong>teste</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="">Senha:&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>teste</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
```